# Function doesn't wait for async/await on addListener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Supposedly, the component needs to wait for `notificationsMixin` to finish before it changes the route, but it doesn't:

**Mixin:**

```
export const notificationsMixin = {
  methods: {
    async notificationsMixin () {
      this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.register()

      this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async (token) => {
        await this.API(token.value)
      })

      this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', () => {
        //
      })
    },
    async API (token) {
      await this.$axios.post('https://api.fexler.com/?action=notifications', token).then(async (response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          await this.$Plugins.Storage.set({
            key: 'token',
            value: JSON.stringify(token)
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
this.notificationsMixin().then(async () => {
  this.$router.push('/profile')
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function resolves immediately.

```js
async notificationsMixin () {
      this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.register()

      this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async (token) => {
        await this.API(token.value)
      })

      this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', () => {
        //
      })
    },
```

Try adding `await`

```js
async notificationsMixin () {
    try {
        await this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.register()

        const token = await this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registration')

        await this.API(token.value)

        this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', () => {
            //
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

> I'm not 100% familiar with this plugin you are using, so you may have
>   to tweak the code a bit. But this should give you an idea of what to
>   do.

As an extra tip, it's not great practice (IMO) to mix `then` with `await`. Pick one and stick with it.

And you don't need `async` here:

```
this.notificationsMixin().then(async () => {
  this.$router.push('/profile')
})
```

change to:

```
this.notificationsMixin().then(() => {
  this.$router.push('/profile')
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that I can make it `const token = await this.$Plugins.PushNotifications.addListener('registration')`. Now it works perfectly! :-)